# Converting TOC of pdf to xml

Tags: python-3.x, pdf

I am learning to code in python .To start with I have taken up an exercise to covert the the toc of a pdf into XML. The exercise has turned more difficult than I had imagined it to be. 
Here is my code:

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pathlib import Path
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from xml.dom import minidom

def prettify(elem):
    """Return a pretty-printed XML string for the Element.
    """
    rough_string = ElementTree.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="  ")

pdfDoc = Path(r'<path of the pdf document>')
fp = open(pdfDoc, 'rb')
parser = PDFParser(fp)
doc = PDFDocument(parser)

outlines = doc.get_outlines()
docLevel = 0
previouslevel = 0
docLevelList = dict()
prevCh = ""
xDoc = Element("root")
for (level, title, dest, a, se) in outlines:
    if title == "Contents":
        pass
    else:
        currCh = title.split(" ",1)[0]

        if len(docLevelList) == 0 and  level == 1:
            docLevelList["ch_"+currCh] = "root"
            previouslevel = level
            prevCh = currCh
            child = SubElement(xDoc, sorted(docLevelList.keys())[-1])
            child.text = title.split(" ",1)[1]

        elif len(docLevelList) != 0 and level == 1 and level < previouslevel:
            docLevelList["ch_"+currCh] = "root"
            previouslevel = level
            prevCh = currCh
            child = SubElement(xDoc, sorted(docLevelList.keys())[-1])
            child.text = title.split(" ",1)[1]

        elif len(docLevelList) != 0 and level == 1 and int(currCh) == int (prevCh) + 1:
            docLevelList["ch_"+currCh] = "root"
            previouslevel = level
            prevCh = currCh
            child = SubElement(xDoc, sorted(docLevelList.keys())[-1])
            child.text = title.split(" ",1)[1]
            #print(docLevelList, previouslevel, prevCh)

        elif len(docLevelList) != 0 and level > previouslevel and prevCh in currCh:
            docLevelList["ch_"+currCh] = "ch_"+prevCh
            previouslevel = level
            prevCh = currCh
            child = SubElement(docLevelList.get(sorted(docLevelList.keys())[-1]), sorted(docLevelList.keys())[-1])
            child.text = title.split(" ",1)[1]

        elif len(docLevelList) != 0 and level == previouslevel and int(prevCh[-1]) + 1 == int(currCh[-1]):
            docLevelList["ch_"+currCh] = docLevelList.get("ch_"+prevCh)
            #docLevelList["ch_"+currCh] = list(docLevelList.keys())[list(docLevelList.values()).index("ch_"+prevCh)]
            previouslevel = level
            prevCh = currCh
            child = SubElement(docLevelList.get(sorted(docLevelList.keys())[-1]), sorted(docLevelList.keys())[-1])
            child.text = title.split(" ",1)[1]

print (prettify(xDoc))
```

The docLevelList.get(sorted(docLevelList.keys())[-1]) bit in the SubElement call is creating a TypeError.

From the error message, I have learned that parent should be an element object but I have run out of ideas. Help!!! 
Also, any other improvement suggestions are most welcome.
Please excuse the pathetic code.

Comment: Add the exact error message to your post. Full details, please.

Comment: I am getting the following error message: `TypeError: SubElement() argument 1 must be xml.etree.ElementTree.Element, not str
`

Comment: Add the exact error message to your post, please. There should also be a line number, the exact line that triggers the error, and possibly more.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Here is the complete error message: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\MyEclipse\TOC parser\tocParser.py", line 69, in <module>
    child = SubElement(docLevelList.get(sorted(docLevelList.keys())[-1]), sorted(docLevelList.keys())[-1])
TypeError: SubElement() argument 1 must be xml.etree.ElementTree.Element, not str`